# Date format exception after setting diiferent locale in android

Tags: android, locale, date-parsing

I have one problem in my application.  I am developing my application for 6 different languages:
1) english 2)russian 3)french 4) italian 5)portugish 6) hindi

Now my application works fine for english language but when I set locale of other language its give me *exception on date parsing and decimal formats* with this function

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
Date date = sdfSource.parse(data.getCdate());
SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

   and with this **function**

DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

abstractAdapter

```
package pl.polidea.coverflow;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * This class is an adapter that provides base, abstract class for images
 * adapter.
 *
 */
public abstract class AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /** The Constant TAG. */
    private static final String TAG = AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    /** The width. */
    private float width = 0;

    /** The height. */
    private float height = 0;

    /** The bitmap map. */
    private final Map<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>> bitmapMap = new HashMap<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>>();

    public AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Set width for all pictures.
     *
     * @param width
     *            picture height
     */
    public synchronized void setWidth(final float width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    /**
     * Set height for all pictures.
     *
     * @param height
     *            picture height
     */
    public synchronized void setHeight(final float height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public final Bitmap getItem(int position) {
        final WeakReference<Bitmap> weakBitmapReference = bitmapMap.get(position);
        if (weakBitmapReference != null) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = weakBitmapReference.get();
            if (bitmap == null) {
         //       Log.v(TAG, "Empty bitmap reference at position: " + position + ":" + this);
            } else {
          //      Log.v(TAG, "Reusing bitmap item at position: " + position + ":" + this);
                return bitmap;
            }
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating item at position: " + position + ":" + this);
        final Bitmap bitmap = createBitmap(position);
        bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    //    Log.v(TAG, "Created item at position: " + position + ":" + this);
        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new bitmap for the position specified.
     *
     * @param position
     *            position
     * @return Bitmap created
     */
    protected abstract Bitmap createBitmap(int position);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    @Override
    public final synchronized long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     * android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public final synchronized ImageView getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            final Context context = parent.getContext();
         //   Log.v(TAG, "Creating Image view at position: " + position + ":" + this);
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams((int) width, (int) height));
        } else {
          //  Log.v(TAG, "Reusing view at position: " + position + ":" + this);
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/white">
        <!-- <view class="pl.polidea.coverflow.CoverFlow" xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pl.polidea.coverflow"
                coverflow:imageWidth="100dip" coverflow:imageHeight="150dip" android:id="@+id/coverflow" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
        </view> -->
    <TextView android:text="STATUS" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"

                android:padding="5dip" android:id="@+id/statusText"></TextView>

        <pl.polidea.coverflow.CoverFlow xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pl.polidea.coverflow"
                coverflow:imageWidth="170dp" coverflow:imageHeight="170dp" coverflow:withReflection="true"
                coverflow:imageReflectionRatio="0.4" coverflow:reflectionGap="4dp" android:id="@+id/coverflowReflect"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="CoverFlow">
        <attr name="imageWidth" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="imageHeight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="withReflection" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="reflectionGap" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="imageReflectionRatio" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```